# Android OpenCV Tutorial 5 Camera Control crash

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-camera

I'm using Android OpenCV v.2.4.3.2 and a Galaxy Nexus phone. When I run the sample "Tutorial 5 - Camera Control", I can see the preview fine and can use the options menu to change the color etc.

But, when I touch the screen to take a picture, the app crashes.

Then, when I try to use the camera again with any app I get "Camera Error: Cannot Connect to Camera". I can only use the camera again by switching the phone off and on again.

I haven't changed any code in the provided sample. Any ideas?

Thanks!

### Log from crash when I try to take a picture:

```
I/JavaCameraView(1278): Preview Frame received. Need to create MAT and deliver it to clients
I/JavaCameraView(1278): Frame size  is 1036800
I/OCVSample::Activity(1278): onTouch event
I/Sample::SampleJavaCameraView(1278): Tacking picture
I/InputDispatcher(220): Application is not responding: Window{41bfb328 org.opencv.samples.tutorial5/org.opencv.samples.tutorial5.Sample5CameraControl paused=false}.  5006.3ms since event,5005.7ms since wait started
I/WindowManager(220): Input event dispatching timed out sending to org.opencv.samples.tutorial5/org.opencv.samples.tutorial5.Sample5CameraControl
I/Process(220): Sending signal. PID: 1278 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(1278): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(1278): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process(220): Sending signal. PID: 220 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(220): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(220): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process(220): Sending signal. PID: 426 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(426): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(426): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process(220): Sending signal. PID: 301 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(301): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(301): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process(220): Sending signal. PID: 440 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(440): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(440): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm(220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 597K, 9% free 17508K/19143K, paused 3ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm(220): GC_EXPLICIT freed 153K, 9% free 17529K/19143K, paused 2ms+3ms
E/ActivityManager(220): ANR in org.opencv.samples.tutorial5 (org.opencv.samples.tutorial5/.Sample5CameraControl)
E/ActivityManager(220): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
E/ActivityManager(220): Load: 0.51 / 0.29 / 0.11
E/ActivityManager(220): CPU usage from 12987ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
E/ActivityManager(220):   58% 1278/org.opencv.samples.tutorial5: 51% user + 6.9% kernel / faults: 57446 minor
E/ActivityManager(220):   26% 120/mediaserver: 24% user + 1.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   1.8% 220/system_server: 1% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 69 minor
E/ActivityManager(220):   1.6% 117/surfaceflinger: 0.7% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 10 minor
E/ActivityManager(220):   1.5% 126/adbd: 0.3% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 39 minor
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.9% 4/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.8% 1121/logcat: 0.4% user + 0.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.6% 23/kinteractiveup: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.6% 76/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.5% 68/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.1% 53/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.3% 5/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0.1% 77/kworker/u:3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   0% 426/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor
E/ActivityManager(220): 46% TOTAL: 39% user + 6.3% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% softirq
E/ActivityManager(220): CPU usage from 371ms to 883ms later with 99% awake:
E/ActivityManager(220):   5.7% 220/system_server: 0% user + 5.7% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):     3.8% 257/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 3.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   1.3% 68/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220):   1.3% 76/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
E/ActivityManager(220): 2.9% TOTAL: 0% user + 2.9% kernel
I/WindowManager(220): createSurface Window{41c0d8f0  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
```

### Log from when I try to use the camera again after the crash:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer(303): Flushing caches (mode 0)
V/CameraHolder(1463): open camera 0
W/CameraService(119): CameraService::connect X (pid 1463) rejected (existing client).
E/CameraHolder(1463): fail to connect Camera
E/CameraHolder(1463): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:302)
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:264)
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1008)
E/CameraHolder(1463):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like app is trying to save photo in UI thread and blocks it (`Application is not responding...` part of first log output)
Crushed app wont release Camera, so when you try to access it again you get error.

Try to move photo saving part to another thread - should work.